# is there another way to group dependencies by which to include for the deployment?

Tags: reactjs, deployment, next.js, dependencies, capacitor

I have a cross-platform app which will be also deployed into web, using Next.js and Capacitor.

Two platforms(Web/App) are sharing some assets and codes and it will be more in the future, so I ended up deciding to keep this system. But the problem is sometimes I need to organize them by its purposes.

I know there's two way to group dependencies by `prod` and `dev`, but it wouldn't work for my case. I want to split them like dependencies for the web, app, and maybe shared(global) one to speed up build process for each deployment.

Or I would say I just want to omit app-specific dependencies like `@capacitor/...` while deploying web part.

Do you have any idea for this? Or should I just pick up another strategy for this case?

Appreciate your thoughts in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Unless your build tool is terrible, packages that are installed but not used will not be part of the build (it might take a few seconds to install them, but then that's it), so you can keep everything in one file (assuming you are using `npm`, that would be `package.json`).

Otherwise you can manage dependencies separately per project, but then you will have the maintenance challenge of making sure the dependencies are updated in each project at the same time.